# How to display Stumbleupon bar on Google Chrome "new tab" page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, stumbleupon

I have the Stumbleupon extension for Chrome and it seems to work fine, except that when I open a new tab and the "most frequently visited sites" page appears, the toolbar doesn't show. Is there any way to make it appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the [StumbleUpon extension page](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/kcahibnffhnnjcedflmchmokndkjnhpg), they state:

> Chrome does not allow DOM injection into some pages so the toolbar is not visible on those pages (including chrome product URLs like the extensions page, and newly opened tabs)

This is in agreement with Chrome's developer documents. From the [Extension Developer FAQ](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/faq.html#faq-dev-15):

> Can I add a content script to `chrome://` URLs?
>
> No. The extensions APIs have been designed to minimize backwards compatibility issues that can arise when new versions of the browser are pushed. Allowing content scripts on `chrome://` URLs would mean that developers would begin to rely on the DOM, CSS, and JavaScript of these pages to stay the same. In the best case, these pages could not be updated as quickly as they are being updated right now. In the worst case, it could mean that an update to one of these pages could cause an extension to break, causing key parts of the browser to stop working for users of that extension.
>
> The reason that [replacing the content](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/override.html) hosted at these URLs entirely is allowed is because it forces an extension developer to implement all of the functionality they want without depending on the browser's internal implementation to stay the same.

Basically, with Chrome's current Extensions API, the only way StumbleUpon would be able to put their bar on to the new tab page would be to completely override the current tab page, which would mean they would have to write their own. This would also mean it would be up to StumbleUpon to make sure that newly installed apps and extensions showed up on the page, etc., which is a lot more work than they probably want to take on.

Comment: Oh well. Why couldn't they allow standard toolbars like every other browser does?